# Airflow Task is marked successful inspite of process failed

Tags: airflow, celery, directed-acyclic-graphs, celery-task

I send task with .send_task method and using the same object to get the result. Task reports successful on Airflow Dashboard inspite of it fails with error on Celery side.

**Here is my DAG look like**

```
RBROKER = "db+sqlite:///db.sqlite3"
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "pyamqp://guest:guest@hostname//"

celery_obj = Celery( 'worker',backend=RBROKER, broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL)

with DAG(
   'redcap_etl',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@once',
) as dag:

def run_celery(**kwargs):
    context=get_current_context()
    print(f"context value: {context}")
    redcap_study = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('redcap_study')
    print(f"redcap_study: {redcap_study}")
    script = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('script')
    print(f"script: {script}")
    row_id = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('row_id')
    print(f"row_id: {row_id}")
    result = celery_obj.send_task("run_redcap_etl", args=[redcap_study,row_id,script])
    print(f"result1 from celery -------: {result}")


start_redcap_etl_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='start_redcap_etl_task',
    bash_command="echo Start redcap etl Task!!"
)

run_redcap_etl_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_redcap_etl_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=run_celery
)

end_rdcap_etl_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='end_rdcap_etl_task',
    bash_command="echo end redcap_etl Task!"
)

# Define the task dependencies
start_redcap_etl_task >> run_redcap_etl_task >> end_rdcap_etl_task
```

**Here is the log from Celery on purpose failure:**

```
    [2024-01-25 21:58:12,961: INFO/MainProcess] celery@ip-10-70-21-144 ready.
[2024-01-25 21:58:57,088: INFO/MainProcess] Task run_redcap_etl[5f4ea609-0da5-4a41-88eb-fb875e35fed9] received
[2024-01-25 21:58:57,089: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] Executing redcap_etl for redcap_study - None script - None and row id is - None
[2024-01-25 21:58:57,126: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] task failed -------
[2024-01-25 21:58:57,126: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task run_redcap_etl[5f4ea609-0da5-4a41-88eb-fb875e35fed9] raised unexpected: TypeError('expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 477, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 760, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/deployment/airflow/deployments/stage/worker.py", line 63, in run_redcap_etl
    result = subprocess.run(["sh", script_path_redcap_etl, script])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 493, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1639, in _execute_child
    self.pid = _posixsubprocess.fork_exec(
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

**Here is the log from Airflow Dashboard:**

```
    *** Found local files:
***   * /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=redcap_etl/run_id=manual__2024-01-25T21:58:52.670290+00:00/task_id=run_redcap_etl_task/attempt=1.log
[2024-01-25, 21:58:56 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=non-requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: redcap_etl.run_redcap_etl_task manual__2024-01-25T21:58:52.670290+00:00 [queued]>
[2024-01-25, 21:58:56 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: redcap_etl.run_redcap_etl_task manual__2024-01-25T21:58:52.670290+00:00 [queued]>
[2024-01-25, 21:58:56 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1308} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2024-01-25, 21:58:56 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1327} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): run_redcap_etl_task> on 2024-01-25 21:58:52.670290+00:00
[2024-01-25, 21:58:56 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:57} INFO - Started process 7185 to run task
[2024-01-25, 21:58:56 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:84} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'redcap_etl', 'run_redcap_etl_task', 'manual__2024-01-25T21:58:52.670290+00:00', '--job-id', '30', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/redcap_etl.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp2a2wt8nn']
[2024-01-25, 21:58:56 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:85} INFO - Job 30: Subtask run_redcap_etl_task
[2024-01-25, 21:58:56 UTC] {task_command.py:410} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: redcap_etl.run_redcap_etl_task manual__2024-01-25T21:58:52.670290+00:00 [running]> on host a3c6392055a0
[2024-01-25, 21:58:56 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1547} INFO - Exporting env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='***' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='redcap_etl' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='run_redcap_etl_task' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2024-01-25T21:58:52.670290+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='1' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='manual__2024-01-25T21:58:52.670290+00:00'
[2024-01-25, 21:58:56 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} INFO - context value: {'conf': <***.configuration.AirflowConfigParser object at 0x7f93a834b250>, 'dag': <DAG: redcap_etl>, 'dag_run': <DagRun redcap_etl @ 2024-01-25 21:58:52.670290+00:00: manual__2024-01-25T21:58:52.670290+00:00, state:running, queued_at: 2024-01-25 21:58:52.690464+00:00. externally triggered: True>, 'data_interval_end': DateTime(2024, 1, 25, 21, 58, 52, 670290, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'data_interval_start': DateTime(2024, 1, 25, 21, 58, 52, 670290, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'ds': '2024-01-25', 'ds_nodash': '20240125', 'execution_date': DateTime(2024, 1, 25, 21, 58, 52, 670290, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'expanded_ti_count': None, 'inlets': [], 'logical_date': DateTime(2024, 1, 25, 21, 58, 52, 670290, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'macros': <module '***.macros' from '/home/***/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/***/macros/__init__.py'>, 'next_ds': '2024-01-25', 'next_ds_nodash': '20240125', 'next_execution_date': DateTime(2024, 1, 25, 21, 58, 52, 670290, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'outlets': [], 'params': {}, 'prev_data_interval_start_success': DateTime(2024, 1, 25, 21, 54, 38, 787991, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'prev_data_interval_end_success': DateTime(2024, 1, 25, 21, 54, 38, 787991, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'prev_ds': '2024-01-25', 'prev_ds_nodash': '20240125', 'prev_execution_date': DateTime(2024, 1, 25, 21, 58, 52, 670290, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'prev_execution_date_success': DateTime(2024, 1, 25, 21, 54, 38, 787991, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'prev_start_date_success': DateTime(2024, 1, 25, 21, 54, 39, 173563, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'run_id': 'manual__2024-01-25T21:58:52.670290+00:00', 'task': <Task(PythonOperator): run_redcap_etl_task>, 'task_instance': <TaskInstance: redcap_etl.run_redcap_etl_task manual__2024-01-25T21:58:52.670290+00:00 [running]>, 'task_instance_key_str': 'redcap_etl__run_redcap_etl_task__20240125', 'test_mode': False, 'ti': <TaskInstance: redcap_etl.run_redcap_etl_task manual__2024-01-25T21:58:52.670290+00:00 [running]>, 'tomorrow_ds': '2024-01-26', 'tomorrow_ds_nodash': '20240126', 'triggering_dataset_events': <Proxy at 0x7f939e3f90f0 with factory <function TaskInstance.get_template_context.<locals>.get_triggering_events at 0x7f939e3d7e60>>, 'ts': '2024-01-25T21:58:52.670290+00:00', 'ts_nodash': '20240125T215852', 'ts_nodash_with_tz': '20240125T215852.670290+0000', 'var': {'json': None, 'value': None}, 'conn': None, 'yesterday_ds': '2024-01-24', 'yesterday_ds_nodash': '20240124', 'templates_dict': None}
[2024-01-25, 21:58:56 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} INFO - redcap_study: None
[2024-01-25, 21:58:56 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} INFO - script: None
[2024-01-25, 21:58:56 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} INFO - row_id: None
[2024-01-25, 21:58:57 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} INFO - result1 from celery -------: 5f4ea609-0da5-4a41-88eb-fb875e35fed9
[2024-01-25, 21:58:57 UTC] {python.py:183} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None
[2024-01-25, 21:58:57 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1350} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=redcap_etl, task_id=run_redcap_etl_task, execution_date=20240125T215852, start_date=20240125T215856, end_date=20240125T215857
[2024-01-25, 21:58:57 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:225} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2024-01-25, 21:58:57 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2653} INFO - 1 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

**Here is screenshot of Task and Dag successful for that run.**

[image]

I have tried `result.get()` to retrieve error and status code from Celery however it is not giving anything back. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Could it be simply that Airflow retried the task and at the second run it succeeded?

Comment: No that is not the case as I am not passing parameters intentionally and without parameters it should not run the sh script successfully. @DejanLekic